# Hiding types from being listed in Assembly.GetTypes in .net

Tags: c#, reflection, assemblies, hidden

Ive been looking everywhere for a possible solution to this but can't seem to find an answer.  My issue is that I have a few classes that need to completely hidden from Assembly.getTypes, as I'm writing a plugin for an application, and it's picking up types that I need to remain hidden (this happens even if they are declared as private or internal classes).

anyone know how to either alter what assembly.GetTyes returns, or an ,aficionado attribute that will keep those types from being listed?

Comment: You can't hide stuff from reflection, it is not a security mechanism.

Comment: @BenRobinson: You can't hide stuff from reflection, because it IS a security mechanism.  The type metadata is used during stack walks and permission testing.

Comment: Sorry i kind of got it back to front, what I meant was that protection levels like protected and internal are not security mechanisms.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is quite a hack and is very fragile, but could work.

Create 2 assemblies -- one for the plug-in and the second for the other types.  The second would be placed in another *known* directory and loaded dynamically into the first when needed.  (For example, via [Assembly.LoadFrom](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1009fa28.aspx).)

The first assembly would then be placed in the plug-in directory and only ever publish its types.  This very fragile because you would likely have to hard-code a path to the second assembly and you run the risk of the file getting deleted or moved.

**EDIT**
@SLaks' comment takes away the fragility of this solution.  If you embed the second assembly as a resource and load it at run-time, the app calling `Assembly.GetTypes` won't see the types you want hidden.

Comment: You could load the second assembly from an embedded resource.

Comment: Excellent idea! Fortunately I the directory isnt an issue because the application exposes directories that I can access, but the resource idea is genius.

Comment: Hmm... slight hitch with this - looks like it is possible for some of these types to be needed before I can get a chance to load the assembly (ie: during a deserialization).
Anyone know a way to hook into a class library's "onLoad", if that makes sense? I also can't seem to find a way to do this.

Comment: @JeremyTang: Handle `AppDomain.AssemblyResolve` before that code runs.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion SLaks, I did try this but unfortunately wasn't able to figure out a way to install the event listener before my objects get instatiated. It seems the issue is a bit of a chicken and egg problem - I have a reference to the assembly I want to load dynamically. So as soon as my main assembly loads it complains that it can't find the other assembly before I get a chance to install the event handler

Comment: @JeremyTang:  Are you working against interfaces or concrete types?

Comment: Concrete types... The objects I create are derivatives of a base class object (defined by the application).  Also the objects in the assembly to be loaded are of deratives too (of the same base class)

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible.
Sorry.

Code that calls `Assembly.GetTypes()` should typically filter for only `public` types.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to managed code.  Complete type information is necessary to .NET's type verifier.  Only native code can be hidden from .NET metadata, and then you give up the portability and permissions supported by pure MSIL.